# How do I get Ubuntu to boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04.

Ubuntu installed but reported it could not install bootloader. I chose the 'continue without bootloader' option.

Then manually install bootloader via boot-repair.

Windows boots but Ubuntu does not (blank screen).

Pastebin file:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11899243/

How do I get Ubuntu to boot?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use your BIOS's boot options menu.  During bootup you will see a screen that says something like 'Press ESC for boot options' or 'Press F8 for boot menu' or something like that.  Press that key and select the hard drive or partition that Ubuntu is on.  Once you're in, you can either attempt to install GRUB, or just keep using the boot menu options to boot into Ubuntu.